Why can't I filter posts in my postgreSQL database by author? (Issue Resolved)
So I have a service where I let users post book reviews. I myself have posted two. In my database I keep track of the user names that they input when submiting a post.
for some weird reason, it will let me filter reviews on my 'home-page' for any author name that I created locally on my own machine, but not for any authors inputted from foreign users. Any one have any idea?
here is the relevant code from my backend:
//Get All Posts
app.get("/", async (req, res) =>{

    let data = await db.query("SELECT * FROM posts");
    posts = data.rows;
    console.log(posts);
    res.render("index.ejs",{
        posts: posts,
    });
});

//Get all posts in order of ascending ID
app.get("/asc", async (req, res) =>{

    let data = await db.query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC");
    posts = data.rows
    console.log(posts)
    res.render("index.ejs",{
        posts: posts,
    });
});

// Get all posts in order of descending ID
app.get("/desc", async (req, res) =>{

    let data = await db.query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC");
    posts = data.rows
    console.log(posts)
    res.render("index.ejs",{
        posts: posts,
    });
});

// Load the new entry page
app.get("/add", async (req, res) =>{
    res.render("new.ejs")
});

// Add entry to database
app.post("/submit", async (req, res) =>{
    let author = req.body.author;
    let book = req.body.book;
    let review = req.body.review;
    let rating = req.body.rating;

    const result = await axios.get(`https://openlibrary.org/search.json?q='%'||${book}||'%'&limit=1`);
    let coverID = result.data.docs[0].cover_edition_key;
    
    const fullDate = new Date()
    const day = fullDate.getDate()
    const month = fullDate.getMonth() + 1
    const year = fullDate.getFullYear()
    let date = `${day}/${month}/${year}`

    await db.query("INSERT INTO posts (author, date, descr, rating, book_auth, cover_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)",
        [author, date, review, rating, book, coverID] );


    res.redirect("/");
});

//Load the update page
app.get("/update:id", async (req, res) =>{
    let id = req.params.id;
    let data = await db.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ($1)",[id]);
    let posts = data.rows[0];
    res.render("new.ejs", {
        posts: posts,
    });

    console.log(posts)
});

//Update post
app.post("/edit:id", async (req, res) =>{
    let id = req.params.id;
    let author = req.body.author;
    let book = req.body.book;
    let review = req.body.review;
    let rating = req.body.rating;
    await db.query("UPDATE posts SET author = ($1), descr = ($2), rating = ($3), book_auth = ($4) WHERE id = ($5)", [author, review, rating, book, id]);
    res.redirect("/");
})

//Filter by author of Review
app.get("/author/:auth", async (req, res) =>{
    let author = req.params.auth;
    let data =  await db.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author ILIKE ($1) AND author IS NOT NULL AND author != ''", [author]);
    let posts = data.rows;
    console.log(author);
    res.render("index.ejs", {
        posts: posts,
    });
});

//Delete post
app.get("/delete:id", async (req, res) =>{
    let id = req.params.id;
    await db.query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ($1)", [id]);

    res.redirect("/");
});

here is the code from my index.EJS:
<% posts.forEach(post => { %>
    
<section class="Posts">
    <div class="leftSide">
      <!--If coverID = Null, render a placeholder cover saved in public images folder-->
      <% if(post.cover_id === null){ %>
        <img class="book-cover" src="/images/images.png">
      <!--Otherwise, fetch the cover for the book using the open library API-->
      <% } else { %>
        <img class="book-cover" src="https://covers.openlibrary.org/b/olid/<%= post.cover_id %>-L.jpg" alt="Book Cover">
      <% } %>
    </div>
      
      <!--On right side, EJS templating displays the details for each post-->
    <div class="rightSide">
        <div class="postContainer">
            <a class="authorTag" href="/author/<%= post.author %>"><h3 class="author"><%= post.author %>'s</a> Review of:</h3>
            <h2 class="book-author"><%= post.book_auth %></h2>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <p class="review"><%= post.descr %></p>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="rating-updateBox">
              <p class="rating">Rating: <%= post.rating %>/10</p>
              <a href="/update<%= post.id %>"><button class="update-Button">Update</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="date-deleteBox">
              <p class="date"><%= post.date %></p>
              <a href="/delete<%= post.id %>"><button class="delete-Button">Delete</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<% });%>

here is my new.EJS where new posts are added
<!--If there is a post, render the update post form instead of the new post form-->
    <% if(locals.posts){ %>

    <form action="/edit<%= posts.id %>" method="post">
        <div id="infoBox">
            <p class="info">Your Name</p>
            <p class="info">Book Name</p>
        </div>
        <div id="auth-titleBox">
          <input id="newAuthor" type="text" name="author" placeholder="Write YOUR name here." required value="<%= posts.author %>">
          <input id="newTitle" type="text" name="book" placeholder="Write the name of the book here." required value="<%= posts.book_auth %>">
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <textarea id="newDesc" name="review" placeholder="Write your review here." required><%= posts.descr %></textarea>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <input id="rating" name="rating" type="number" min="0" max="10" placeholder="Rating" required value="<%= posts.rating %>">
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </form>

    <% } else { %>
    
    <!--New post form-->    
    <form action="/submit" method="post">
        <div id="infoBox">
            <p class="info">Your Name</p>
            <p class="info">Book Name</p>
        </div>
        <div id="auth-titleBox">
          <input id="newAuthor" type="text" name="author" placeholder="Write YOUR name here." required>
          <input id="newTitle" type="text" name="book" placeholder="Write the name of the book here." required>
        </div>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <textarea id="newDesc" name="review" placeholder="Write your review here." required></textarea>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <input id="rating" name="rating" type="number" min="0" max="10" placeholder="Rating" required>
        <input id="submit" type="submit">
    </form>

    <% } %>


When displaying the post details on the front end, each post has the author of the review's name displayed at the top. This name is a href that includes the post's author's name as a parameter. Then, in the backend, I parse that parameter and render all the posts from my databse where the author name matches the parsed parameter. This works, but only for authors I have created on my machine. Not for any author names other users created, despite the fact that those author values were saved to my database as I can see them in pgAdmin in the table.

We need more details here. How are you writing the data to your database exactly? This could be any number of problems, for example an encoding issue with the usernames. Are you properly sanitizing the inputs? Are there spaces or stuff like that in the usernames?

I've eddited the post to show the rest of my server code. The author that I can successfully filter has a space in it and works fine. The others that done work have no spaces. If I add my own author name with no spaces it will still work. It just doesn't let me filter any author name that I myself didn't add to the database

I've also gone and added my new.ejs code where posts users input their names and such. Could the issue be here?

welcome to stackoverflow Dexedus, have you make sure the query actually works? i do think SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author ILIKE ($1) AND author IS NOT NULL AND author != '' is kinda overkill with the author IS NOT NULL AND author != '', i mean, both most likely won't even satisfy the ILIKE as long as [author] is not null and not an empty string. i feel the question is having an information overload that makes it hard to read at a glance.

Also, if both you and foreign users insert the data to the database via your website, it wouldn't make a difference, as the server would always be the one actually inserting it. Can you confirm that the data foreign users entered is present in the database?

Thanks guys, I managed to find the problem. The foreign user had inputted the author name with a space at the end of the input which seems to be causing the problem. Spaces within the author name seem to be fine, but just that space after the last character is the problem. I added a .trim() method to the variable that parses the inputted author name in the add post route. Seems to have fixed my problem! Thanks again!

I found the issue. Just thought I'd post this incase anyone has the same issue.
The users inputted their author name with a space after the last character in the name. This caused the issue. I just added a .trim() method to the end of my variable that parsed the author input in my route that added posts to the database. This has resolved the problem.
// Add entry to database
app.post("/submit", async (req, res) =>{
    let author = req.body.author.trim();

Thanks

Always trim inputs, I don't even trust myself to not accidentally add a space.

@GreenSaiko Yeah, I only started learning to code 3 months ago so still learning some things the hard way ha
